# Spring Batch doesn't call both ItemProcessor and ItemWriter in chunk-flow

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application to get a file in samba server
and generate a new file in a different folder on the same server.
However,
only ItemReader is called in the flow.
What is the problem? Thanks.

**BatchConfiguration:**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends BaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ValeTrocaItemReader reader() {
        return new ValeTrocaItemReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public ValeTrocaItemProcessor processor() {
        return new ValeTrocaItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ValeTrocaItemWriter writer() {
        return new ValeTrocaItemWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory()
                .get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .repository(getJobRepository())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(this.step1())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory()
                .get("step1")
                .<ValeTroca, ValeTroca>chunk(10)
                .reader(this.reader())
                .processor(this.processor())
                .writer(this.writer())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**BaseConfiguration:**

```java
public class BaseConfiguration implements BatchConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public SimpleJobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        final SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(this.getJobRepository());
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(this.getTransactionManager()).getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean repositoryFactory = this.getMapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        return new SimpleJobExplorer(repositoryFactory.getJobInstanceDao(), repositoryFactory.getJobExecutionDao(),
                repositoryFactory.getStepExecutionDao(), repositoryFactory.getExecutionContextDao());
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean getMapJobRepositoryFactoryBean() {
        return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(this.getTransactionManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory() throws Exception {
        return new JobBuilderFactory(this.getJobRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory() throws Exception {
        return new StepBuilderFactory(this.getJobRepository(), this.getTransactionManager());
    }
}
```

**ValeTrocaItemReader:**

```java
@Configuration
public class ValeTrocaItemReader implements ItemReader<ValeTroca>{

    @Value(value = "${url}")
    private String url;

    @Value(value = "${user}")
    private String user;

    @Value(value = "${password}")
    private String password;

    @Value(value = "${domain}")
    private String domain;

    @Value(value = "${inputDirectory}")
    private String inputDirectory;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ValeTroca read() throws MalformedURLException, SmbException, IOException, Exception {
        File tempOutputFile = getInputFile();

        DefaultLineMapper<ValeTroca> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
            {
                setDelimiter(";");
                setNames(new String[]{"id_participante", "cpf", "valor"});
            }
        });
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(
                new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<ValeTroca>() {
            {
                setTargetType(ValeTroca.class);
            }

        });

        FlatFileItemReader<ValeTroca> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(new FileUrlResource(tempOutputFile.getCanonicalPath()));
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        itemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());

        tempOutputFile.deleteOnExit();
        return itemReader.read();
    }
```

**Sample of ItemProcessor:**

```java
public class ValeTrocaItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ValeTroca, ValeTroca> {

    @Override
    public ValeTroca process(ValeTroca item)  {
        //Do anything

        ValeTroca item2 = item;
        System.out.println(item2.getCpf());
        return item2;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
- Spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE - Spring batch 4.1.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: The problem was that even though I'm not using any databases, the spring batch, although configured to have the JobRepository in memory, needs a database (usually H2) to save the configuration tables, jobs, etc.

In this case, the dependencies of JDBC and without H2 in pom.xml were disabled. Just added them to the project and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your configuration, here are a couple of notes:

- `BatchConfiguration` looks good. That's a typical job with a single chunk-oriented step.
- `BaseConfiguration` is actually the default configuration you get when using `@EnableBatchProcessing` without providing a datasource. So this class can be removed
- Adding `@Configuration` on `ValeTrocaItemReader` and marking the method `read()` with `@Bean` is not correct. This means your are declaring a bean named `read` of type `ValeTroca` in your application context. Moreover, your custom reader uses a `FlatFileItemReader` but has no added value compared to a `FlatFileItemReader`. You can declare your reader as a `FlatFileItemReader` and configure it as needed (resource, line mapper, etc ). This will also avoid the mistake of opening the execution context in the `read` method, which should be done when initializaing the reader or in the [`ItemStream#open`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html#open-org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext-) method if the reader implements `ItemStream`

Other than that, I don't see from what you shared why the processor and writer are not called.